# VueJS convention and scope

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I looked in the documentation, on the forum ... I would like to know this:

- When I create a component with a scoped style. Should I use classes or id for my DOM ? I prefer ID because this element is unique.

  ex:

  ```
  <template>
    <div id="wrapper"> // or class="wrapper" ?
      <button id="myBtn">CLICK</button>  // or class="myBtn" ?
      <div v-for="i in 5" :key="i" class="myDiv">{{i}}</div>  // sure class in this case :D
    </div>
  </template>
  ```
- For the methods of the component must prefix by $ _mycomposant_methods or can I directly write method?
- Same for computed?

I imagine that when compiling (webpack) each component is scoped but I would like to be sure to avoid edge effects.

Thank you

Comment: It's widely considered really bad practice using ID selectors in CSS.

Comment: I'm not really agree. A header or a footer is unique in all my page. I prefer use an ID instead of a class.

Comment: The general rule of thumb is **never make any selector more specific than necessary**. Using `id` selectors clearly massively violates this principle - even moreso when being used to specify context. First come `id` or overly long, DOM-mimicking selectors, then comes `!important`, and in the blink of an eye you're in the middle of a neverending specificity war with `!important` spreading like cancer in growing projects.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need either.
Vue will automatically take care of the scope and give the component a unique data-hash which then is taken to write your css. It really works well. Give it a try ;)

And your methods and computed properties are working just like normal. nothing to take care of.

Comment: Heard. I knew it was segregated, however, I wanted to know the overall good practice.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, I think you should keep using class.
Although with the help of component-scoped CSS, you don't need to worry much about the interference from other components' stylesheets, all the templates will still be merged into one document. Vue.js just adds unique data attributes to the elements, it doesn't guarantee every id's uniqueness you defined.
So in order to keep flexibility and avoid potential troubles, it will be a wise choice to follow specifications of HTML which means keeping `wrapper` as a class if it appears in your HTML document several times.

For the second and third question, I prefer to keep the method names easy to read and understandable. All the JavaScript code will going to be minified and uglified, so there's no need to add any prefix.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I'm agree